# `Missing $ inserted` when using math mode in .bib

Tags: math-mode, bibliographies, symbols, biber

```
@article{soffa1989decomposition,
  title={DECOMPOSITION AND ORDERING PROCESSES INVOLVING THERMODYNAMICALLY FIRST-ORDER ORDER{$\,\to\,$}DISORDER TRANSFORMATIONS},
  author={Soffa, WA and Laughlin, DE},
  journal={Acta Metallurgica},
  volume={37},
  number={11},
  pages={3019--3028},
  year={1989},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
```

One of my references in the .bib file is as above. I get the following errors when I try to compile the .tex file:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
$
l.114
I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.



! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
$
l.114
I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.



! \OML/cmm/m/it/12 DISORDERTRANSFORMATIONS$\OT1/ptm/m/n/12 .
[]
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `BeforeClearDocument' on input line 115.
[4]
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AfterLastShipout' on input line 115.
(Notes_Svib_ODT.aux)
Package atveryend Info: Executing hook `AtVeryEndDocument' on input line 115.
Package atveryend Info: Executing hook `AtEndAfterFileList' on input line 115.
Package rerunfilecheck Info: File `Notes_Svib_ODT.out' has not changed.
(rerunfilecheck) Checksum: D41D8CD98F00B204E9800998ECF8427E;0.
Package logreq Info: Writing requests to 'Notes_Svib_ODT.run.xml'.
\openout1 = `Notes_Svib_ODT.run.xml'.
)
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
12367 strings out of 492449
221181 string characters out of 3119992
688515 words of memory out of 3000000
16549 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
25836 words of font info for 53 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
40i,7n,45p,899b,1223s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
{C:/Users/admin/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/enc/dvips/base/8r.enc
}<C:/Users/admin/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/
cm/cmmi12.pfb><C:/Users/admin/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/pub
lic/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb><C:/Users/admin/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/fon
ts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy10.pfb><C:/Users/admin/AppData/Local/Programs/M
iKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy6.pfb><C:/Users/admin/AppData/Loca
l/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/urw/times/utmb8a.pfb><C:/Users/admin/AppData/
Local/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/urw/times/utmr8a.pfb><C:/Users/admin/AppD
ata/Local/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/urw/times/utmri8a.pfb>
Output written on Notes_Svib_ODT.pdf (4 pages, 97925 bytes).
PDF statistics:
96 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
30 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Changing `$\,\to\,$` to `$\rightarrow$` doesn't change anything. Please help me resolve this issue or suggest a way to incorporate symbols like arrows in the bibliography through biber(.bib) or any other way.

Comment: please add the error message from the log in a code block (`{}`) so line endings preserved, show the full error from `!` to `?` it is almost impossible to read as posted above, and you do not show the missing `$` errors at all

Comment: the usual reason for that error in a bib file is some entry has a `_` intended as text but starting a math subscript and giving an error.

Comment: The entry in question appeared to be working for me in a short example document I just ran. Can you please provide a full example document that cites this entry and reproduces the error?

Comment: This is only a style issue and has nothing to do with the issue at hand, but still I would recommend you change the `title` from ALL CAPS to a more sane capitalisation style such as `title = {Decomposition and Ordering Processes Involving Thermodynamically First-Order Order${\,\to\,}$Disorder Transformations},`. It is also recommended to add spaces and dots to initials, so Biber/BIbTeX can parse the name correctly (`author = {Soffa, W. A. and Laughlin, D. E.},`; if you want a different output that can be arranged - the option `terseinits` might be interesting)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I hope the edit is fine. The .bib file doesn't have a `_`.

@moewe I took the BibTeX entry from science direct. Google scholar gives the following entry: ```@article{soffa1989decomposition,
  title={Decomposition and ordering processes involving thermodynamically first-order order→ disorder transformations},
  author={Soffa, WA and Laughlin, DE},
  journal={Acta Metallurgica},
  volume={37},
  number={11},
  pages={3019--3028},
  year={1989},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}```, but this doesn't work because of the arrow symbol.

Comment: @moewe I apologise but this is part of my research article, so can't share ethe .tex file.

Comment: you are not really giving enough information for anyone to help, the log file would show which file is being read, are you sure it is related to the bib entry that you show? in any case delete the .aux and .bbl files and try again with generating new auxiliary files,

Comment: The fact that it is your research does not stop you posting an example that shows the problem. take a copy of your document, deleet everything you can while still showing the issue, then once it is small enough to post you can change every word to `duck` it really doesn't matter what the text says so long as it generates the error that you are asking about.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle removing the .aux and .bbl files worked. I don't understand though, I spent the last 2 hours trying to resolve these errors, and just removing these files worked.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Could you help me understand how I should have posted the errors? I don't seem to understand what you're pointing out. I copied the whole message I get in texmaker (just below the editor).

Comment: you presumably had a version with the arrow not marked as math so generating errors, then edits to the bib file do noting unless you regenerate the bbl with bibtex. or maybe the error was in the aux file not the bbl, really you have not provided enough information, but sometimes I get a lucky guess:-)

Comment: the real tex errors are in the `.log` file, most editors only show a small part of teh log and often corrupt the messages (I don't know texmaker though, perhaps it does this better than some)

Comment: You don't need to post your article here (and indeed we don't want you to post your complete research here), but it should be possible (with a bit of work) to reduce your document to a short example that contains little to no traces of your research (if you need text to show the issue, you can use dummy text) and yet still reproduces the error (a so-called MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)

Comment: @moewe I realised that after David Carlisle's suggestion. My apologies, I seem to understand quantum mechanics fairly well but latex is somehow giving me a hard time.
Removing the .aux and .bbl files worked. Thank you for helping out.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thank you for the suggestion, will keep that in mind. Also, thank you for your help.